# Как реализовать данный функционал в верстке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать данную штуку в верстке? то есть это картинка, на которой висит background-image или какие-то бордеры? сижу втыкаю и вообще понять не могу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если кому-то сложно понять, то это не значит, что не найдутся такие, которые поймут

Answer (score 1):

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>У лукоморья дуб зелёный</legend>
  <p>
    У лукоморья дуб зелёный;<br/> Златая цепь на дубе том:<br/> И днём и ночью кот учёный<br/> Всё ходит по цепи кругом;<br/> Идёт направо — песнь заводит,<br/> Налево — сказку говорит.<br/> Там чудеса: там леший бродит,<br/> Русалка на ветвях сидит;<br/>    Там на неведомых дорожках<br/> Следы невиданных зверей;<br/> Избушка там на курьих ножках<br/> Стоит без окон, без дверей;<br/> Там лес и дол видений полны;<br/> Там о заре прихлынут волны<br/> На брег песчаный и пустой,<br/> И тридцать витязей прекрасных<br/>    Чредой из вод выходят ясных,<br/> И с ними дядька их морской;<br/> Там королевич мимоходом<br/> Пленяет грозного царя;<br/> Там в облаках перед народом<br/> Через леса, через моря<br/> Колдун несёт богатыря; В темнице там царевна тужит,<br/> А бурый
    волк ей верно служит;<br/> Там ступа с Бабою Ягой<br/> Идёт, бредёт сама собой,<br/> Там царь Кащей над златом чахнет;<br/> Там русский дух… там Русью пахнет!<br/> И там я был, и мёд я пил;<br/> У моря видел дуб зелёный;<br/> Под ним сидел, и кот
    учёный<br/> Свои мне сказки говорил.<br/>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Афигеть) спасибо большое за ответ, не знал про такую штукенцию)